# Old "DEV401" vs New "Platform App Builder" exam

Tags: certification, dev401, app-builder

I would like to know more about the new "Platform App Builder exam" with respect to old DEV401. Is this newly introduced exam is just a rename of old DEV401 exam with same old "Study Plan" for DEV401?.

Or is this "Platform App Builder exam" something new Salesforce introduced with a new study plan. Also any change for the "Platform Developer I & 2 exam" after ceasing DEV401 and introduction of "Platform App Builder exam"?

Can someone please help me in understanding in this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best place to get more info on this is the study guide for each of these exams .

**[App Builder](http://certification.salesforce.com/app-builders)**

The course recommended for App Builder is the same course that was needed for developer exam before .Remember that 401 is not the exam name and it was a course name .

Both the exams focus on the declarative features of the platform .The best place to get what topics to be covered is documented in the [Study Guide](http://certification.salesforce.com/SG_CertifiedPlatformAppBuilder.pdf?v=7)

The difference I found between developer exam and App builder is App builder also focus on the latest features added to the platform like Lightning App Builder , Salesforce 1 Mobile Configurations ,Process Builder Automation,App Deployment and Application Lifecycle management.So Apart from reading previous content for Developer exam also focus on these Topics .

**[Platform Developer I](http://certification.salesforce.com/platform-developers)**

Platform 1 is very different than previous developer exam .This exam now focus on both declarative and the programmatic capabilities .It does not test your in depth knowledge of Apex and Visualforce but basics of apex and visualforce is tested .You should have clear knowledge of when to go for declarative features and when declarative features wont full fill your need .Again [Study guide](http://certification.salesforce.com/SG_CertifiedPlatformDeveloperI.pdf?v=7) is your best friend here .You should have great command over building data models and logic using declarative and programmatic features .

**[Platform Developer 2](http://certification.salesforce.com/platform-developers)**

This is similar to the advanced developer exam we had previously .It includes multiple choice followed by assignment and essay exams .The candidate is also expected to know Integrations and best practices for app development and deployment .

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was so detailed thats I will be able to prepare for the certification as I got some study materials related to DEV401.

Comment: Also note Trailhead has got some nice content as well to start with .

Comment: I had already complted mst of Trailhead with rlted to the Basic ADMIN & Developer. Now planning to luk more detailed on Study plan for ADM201 1st & more detailed study using certiedondemand. I dont hav  any wrk exprnce in Salesforce and I am trying to learn it myself with bits and pieces which I am getting in btwn my daily work in Mainframes at IT firm for a career change. Plz let me knw if there anything else other than TrailHeads, certfiedondemand, adminhero,udacity & sdfc99 which I can refer 4 my preparation of exam. Expecting more support and help from you going 4wrd to achieve my goal.

Comment: There are various workbooks available. like apex workbook and vf workbooks .These are great to get hands dirty on .